# Reference getting passed through bundle in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-bundle

I am passing data through bundle from fragment1 to fragment2.

Fragment1 Code :

```
SecondFragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("SendPojo", sendPojo);
    secondFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.layout, secondFragment, "Second Fragment");
    transaction.addToBackStack("Second Fragment");
    transaction.commit();
```

Fragment2 Code :

```
SendPojo sendPojo;
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    SendPojo sendPojo = (SendPojo) bundle.getSerializable("SendPojo");
    sendPojo.data = "Changed";
```

Pojo class code :

```
public class SendPojo implements Serializable {
    public transient String data = "";
}
```

I am getting same reference in both fragment for SendPojo. On changing data on second fragment, data in first fragment is changed automatically. Because reference is same.

So on pressing back button also, data is getting changed. But i dont want any change on pressing back button.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Please share the pojo of SendPojo

Comment: Hi aditya. Problem was with shallow copy. It was maintaining shallow copy of the pooja. Now it's fixed. Cheers.

Comment: Thought so, asked for the pojo just to confirm that :) happy to know it worked

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new reference of the `Pojo` in the second fragment and transfer the data from the first `Pojo`to the second. Thus you would have two different references while transfering the data from one to the other.

Comment: Already tried. No success.                                                                     SendPojo sendPojo new SendPojo();
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    SendPojo sendPojo = (SendPojo) bundle.getSerializable("SendPojo");
    sendPojo.data = "Changed";